# Combining multiple rows in SQL with distinct identifier

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm pulling some data from SQL Server from this table.

```
ID_Number    Date_01     Date_02     Date_03    Date_04     Date_05
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1001         6/1/2015    6/5/2015    Null       Null        6/6/2015
1001         Null        Null        6/5/2015   Null        6/7/2015
1002         6/20/2015   Null        Null       6/21/2015   Null
1002         6/21/2015   6/22/2015   6/23/2015  6/19/2015   6/20/2015
1003         6/25/2015   Null        Null       6/26/2015   6/29/2015
```

I'm not sure what CTE query will I use to return only one row per ID and get the max date per column for each ID.

Here's the sample result:

```
ID_Number    Date_01      Date_02     Date_03    Date_04     Date_05
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1001         6/1/2015     6/5/2015    6/5/2015   Null        6/7/2015
1002         6/21/2015    6/22/2015   6/23/2015  6/21/2015   6/20/2015
1003         6/25/2015    Null        Null       6/26/2015   6/29/2015
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `CTE` to do this, If am not wrong simple `Group by` with `Max` aggregate should work for you

```
select 
  ID_Number,    
  Date_01=max(Date_01),
  Date_02=max(Date_02),
  Date_03=max(Date_03),
  Date_04=max(Date_04),
  Date_05=max(Date_05)
from yourtable
group by ID_Number
```

Answer (score 0):

> max date per column for each ID

Grouping by ID_Number :

```
SELECT        ID_Number AS Expr1, MAX(Date_01) AS Date_01, MAX(Date_02) AS Date_02, MAX(Date_03) AS Date_03, MAX(Date_04) AS Date_04, MAX(Date_05) AS Date_05
FROM            ta1
GROUP BY ID_Number
```